# Variable merging which doesn't make sense

Tags: php, variables

Consider this code:

```
$x  = 1.4;
$i1 = 0.5;
$i2 = 0.4;

echo ($i1 + $i2 = $x); // Outputs 1.9
```

Why is this? I've tried searching for this kind of variable setup without results. Is the variable `$i2` being ignored? Why use this over `echo ($x + $i1);`? It outputs the same result.

Comment: Why is this? -> [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), like PEMDAS rule but for PHP.

Answer (score 5):

The point is that it does **two** things in one statement.

It is shorthand for:

```
$i2 = $x;
echo ($i1 + $i2);
```

The assignment happens inline, saving the separate line.  Not ideal style, but often used in `if()`, `while()` and other control statements.

Comment: Another way to look at it is: `($i1 + ($i2 = $x))`. An assignment operation evaluates the new value of the variable to the left of the assignments.

Comment: @Andrew Curioso: Yes, that is how the operator precedence works there.  `+` has higher binding priority in most C-style languages, but `($i1 + $i2) = $x` means nothing.

Comment: like while ( $result = mysql_fetch_array($res))

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: Aye, that is amongst the most common uses, it is actually quite sensible on a loop condition in that context to set variables, for-loops do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

that would be $i1 + the assignment.

The assignment evaluates to $x  `($i2 = $x )`

the end result is `echo 0.5 + 1.4.`

Even php has operator priorities http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has [The Little Schemer](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/) usually on top of a book pile near the desk, I say shame. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling we are laughing all the way to our next lexical scope

Comment: Not even but because php has operator precendence. +1 for the link.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is treated before `+`, which means that this is what happens:

```
echo ($i1 + ($i2 = $x));
```

Comment: wrong. `=` is not treated before `+`, check the docs, `+` has a higher precedence than `=`.

Comment: @hakre. In that case, the result is completely illogical.

Comment: Or the way how you think about it is illogical. Depends on the point of view maybe. Otherwise I have not seen that many bugreports for the [page in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).